# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,$ $b,$ $c,$ $d,$ $e,$ $f$ be nonnegative real numbers.

(a) Prove that
$$(a^2 + b^2)^2 (c^4 + d^4)(e^4 + f^4) \ge (ace + bdf)^4.$$

(b) Prove that
$$(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)(e^2 + f^2) \ge (ace + bdf)^2.$$

I'm not sure how I should start approaching both problems. I believe I should use Cauchy-Schwarz, but I'm not sure.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't Cauchy-Schwarz something like $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\ge(ac+bd)^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both CS inequality applications, you should try yourself.  Here is the first one:

1. $(c^4+d^4)(e^4+f^4) \geqslant (c^2e^2+d^2f^2)^2$
2. $(a^2+b^2)(c^2e^2+d^2f^2) \geqslant (ace+bdf)^2$

Now combine the two to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'll try it out! :)

Comment: Also, what does ⩾ symbol mean in your solution?

Comment: Greater than or equal to.

Comment: On the second (b) part, if you want a hint, just note $(c^2+d^2)(e^2+f^2) \geqslant (c^2e^2+d^2f^2)$ is a crude estimate, but sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much!

Comment: @infinity I see Macavity is using a  symbol \geqslant   which is present in Latex   https://www.caam.rice.edu/~heinken/latex/symbols.pdf

Comment: @In-finite #1 times #2 squared is (a).

Answer (score -1):

For (a),
Just use Holder's Inequality.

For (b), 
Expand $(a^2 + b^2) (c^2 + d^2) (e^2 + f^2) $. (It is equivalent to the LHS of my answer) 
Expand $(ace + bdf)^2$. (It is equivalent to the RHS of my answer) 
The problem is just proving
$$
a^2 c^2 e^2 + a^2 c^2 f^2 + a^2 d^2 e^2 + a^2 d^2 f^2 + b^2 c^2 e^2 + b^2 c^2 f^2 + b^2 d^2 e^2 + b^2 d^2 f^2 \ge a^2 c^2 e^2 + b^2 d^2 f^2 + 2abcdef
$$ or
$$
a^2 c^2 f^2 + a^2 d^2 e^2 + a^2 d^2 f^2 + b^2 c^2 e^2 + b^2 c^2 f^2 + b^2 d^2 e^2 \ge 2abcdef \quad \textrm{By cancelling 2 terms on the left and right side.}
$$
Now, that is just
$$
(acf - bde)^2 + a^2 d^2 e^2 + a^2 d^2 f^2 + b^2 c^2 e^2 + b^2 c^2 f^2 \ge 0
$$
We have proved by this that the inequality is valid for any real numbers, not only non-negative ones.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last part of your answer. Could you elaborate more? (I'm kind of confused...)

Comment: @In-finite See. I have detailed the answer now. Wish it suffices you ... $\ddot \smile$.

Comment: I still don't understand how your answer proves Part (b)... How does proving that the inequality is $\geq$ 0 prove that the inequality I posted is true?

Comment: @In-finite Because the expression which I proved greater than $0$ is same as the inequality itself, so the expression is greater than $0$, hence the inequality is true.

Comment: @In-finite Do you agree $(acf - bde)^2 + a^2d^2e^2 + a^2d^2f^2 + b^2c^2e^2 + b^2c^2f^2\ge0$ is true?

Comment: Oh ok, I got it.

Comment: Why down-vote here?